# iOS Implicit conversion of int to NSNumber is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnumber

on following code i'm get the errormessage: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with ARC.

What i'm making wrong?

```
<pre>
 <code>
  NSDictionary *results = [jsonstring JSONValue];
  NSNumber *success = [results objectForKey:@"success"]; // possible values for "success": 0 or 1

   if (success == 1) { // ERROR implicit conversion of int to NSNumber disallowed with ARC    
   }
 </code>
</pre>
```

Thanks for any help or hint!

regards, Daniel

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `[success intValue] == 1`. An NSNumber is a class, so number is a pointer, not the direct value.

Answer (score 28):

Erro because you are comparing `NSNumber` with `int`.

Try like -

```
if ([success isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])
```

or

```
if ([success intValue] == 1)
```

Comment: The first comparison is wrong, you're comparing pointer values of distinct objects. You'd want `[success isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]` or better yet, the second comparison.

Answer (score 3):

`NSNumber` is an object (i.e. a pointer), so you can't just compare it to a integer literal like `1`. Instead you have to extract the `int` value from the number object:

```
if ([success intValue] == 1) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `success` should indicate a boolean, you may want to try this

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonstring JSONValue];
NSNumber *success = [results objectForKey:@"success"]; 

if ([success boolValue]) { 
  // success!
}
```